# c# start console application in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make launcher for my games and I like to add music player in background, but if I start the process it instantly fail's.

**Code**

```
private void btnStartMusic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new 
    ProcessStartInfo("MusicPlayer\\MemequickieMusicPlayer.exe");
    proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.RedirectStandardError = false;
    proc.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.Start(proc);
}
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Ask if you are missing some information.

Comment: Care to share the error message?

Comment: It instantly exists so i can't see error message.

Comment: Try running your application from the console. Is your MemequickieMusicPlayer.exe inside your bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path to the exe and setting the working directory; assuming the exe is in your executable folder:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MusicPlayer");

ProcessStartInfo proc = new 
    ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(path, "MemequickieMusicPlayer.exe")); 

proc.WorkingDirectory = path;
```

If the error persists and you want to debug the output, change:

```
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Create the process like this:

```
Process process = new Process(proc);
process.Start();

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```

You should now see the output in your output window.

Comment: I did little differently, but i used this as reference. Thanks For Help.